# How to change opacity of NSImageview in Xamarin.mac

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

mac to develop an application for mac. I am struggling for changing opacity of imageview which is in background. When i try to access that control in viewcontroller.h file it shows me no overloads for nsimageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSImageView` have an Alpha property (ObjC = `setAlphaValue:`) that accepts a float value.

#### Example:

```
imageView.AlphaValue = 0.5f;
```